# Batch converting PNG to JPG in linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, jpeg, png

Does anyone know a good way to batch-convert a bunch of PNGs into JPGs in linux? (I'm using Ubuntu).

A png2jpg binary that I could just drop into a shell script would be ideal.

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

I am not an expert in the actual usage, but I know you can pretty much do anything image-related with this!

An example is:

```
convert image.png image.jpg
```

which will keep the original as well as creating the converted image.

As for batch conversion, I think you need to use the [Mogrify](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) tool which is part of ImageMagick.

Keep in mind that this **overwrites** the old images.

The command is:

```
mogrify -format jpg *.png
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was after and will be using again. By the way, just to clarify as I didn't realise this is what you meant: convert is used to generate a separate output file, mogrify is used to modify the original image.

Comment: png images with transparent background does not convert properly to jpg.

Comment: To convert PNG's with transparent background, use the following command: `mogrify -format jpg -background black -flatten *.png`

Comment: I wonder how can this overwrite original files *if* the filename changes... in fact jpg files keep untouched ;) Ah, +1

Comment: @neurino The file name isn't changed in the mogrify example.  The files still have a `.png` extension but are jpeg images.  Try using `file img.png` (after running mogrify) and it will tell you that it is a jpeg image.

Comment: @KevinCox on my linux box after `mogrify -format jpeg img.png` I have 2 files and `file img.*` reports one png, the original untouched, and a new jpeg one. So `mogrify` does **not** overwrite original files in this case.

Comment: @neurino Interesting.  From the mogrify man page: "mogrify  -  resize  an  image,  blur, crop, despeckle, dither, draw on, flip, join, re-sample, and much more. Mogrify overwrites  the  original image file, whereas, convert(1) writes to a different image file."  So I don't know why that happens on your box.

Comment: @neurino This happens on my box as well.  Now I'm really confused, it this a bug?  Or an undocumented feature?

Comment: From `mogrify` documentation: "*This tool is similiar to `convert` except that the original image file is overwritten (unless you change the file suffix with the **-format** option) with any changes you request.*"

Comment: If you need to compress your png's more use `mogrify -quality 75 -format jpg *.png`

Comment: Me too on Ubuntu Desktop 16 today - original files remain

Answer (score 123):

I have a couple more solutions.

The simplest solution is like most already posted.  A simple bash for loop.

```
for i in *.png ; do convert "$i" "${i%.*}.jpg" ; done
```

For some reason I tend to avoid loops in bash so here is a more unixy xargs approach, using bash for the name-mangling.

```
ls -1 *.png | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'convert "$0" "${0%.*}.jpg"'
```

The one I use.  It uses GNU Parallel to run multiple jobs at once, giving you a performance boost.  It is installed by default on many systems and is almost definitely in your repo (it is a good program to have around).

```
ls -1 *.png | parallel convert '{}' '{.}.jpg'
```

The number of jobs defaults to the number of CPU cores you have.  I found better CPU usage using 3 jobs on my dual-core system.

```
ls -1 *.png | parallel -j 3 convert '{}' '{.}.jpg'
```

And if you want some stats (an ETA, jobs completed, average time per job...)

```
ls -1 *.png | parallel --eta convert '{}' '{.}.jpg'
```

There is also an alternative syntax if you are using GNU Parallel.

```
parallel convert '{}' '{.}.jpg' ::: *.png
```

And a similar syntax for some other versions (including debian).

```
parallel convert '{}' '{.}.jpg' -- *.png
```

Comment: +1 for correct bash string expansion in the for, if I could give you another upvote for mentioning parallel, I would. There's one typo, however - you need a `done` at the end of that for loop. Also, for the parallel stuff, you could avoid using that `ls` and pipe with a construct like: `parallel -j 3 --eta convert '{}' '{.}.jpg' ::: *.png` (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__reading_arguments_from_command_line))

Comment: Fixed typo.  That is a cool syntax that I didn't know of.  I don't know which one I like better for probably the same reason I prefer not to use loops in bash.  I put it the solution because it is probably the more "proper" way but I'll probably stick with the `ls` method for myself because it makes more sense to me.

Comment: ...although it should be noted that that syntax only works on GNU parallel. The parallel that's packaged in some linux distros (like Debian & Ubuntu) is actually a different version with a slightly different syntax (use `--` rather than `:::`) - and even then, it frustratingly lacks some of the features of GNU parallel.

Comment: (though those on distros that don't package GNU parallel can install it from source quite easily, using the instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/142757/112879))

Comment: I think I should change it back then so that it works with as many versions as possible.

Comment: If you have a directory with more than 10,000 png images in it... the ls command will likely fail. So, this command works in those situations: `find . -type f -name '*.png' | parallel --eta convert '{}' '{.}.jpg'`

Comment: I've learnt so much from this answer.

Comment: Be careful in using any of above command as it will mess up the background. I tried few commands and none worked. Always have a backup of your folder.  @KevinCox you should test commands before posting as I messed up my images.

Comment: @Raymond all of these commands are testing and work fine. You would have to share more information for any help. What is "the background" and how is it messed up? One first step would be to check that you don't have any aliases or other custom commands that may be running instead of the commands intended by the answer.

Comment: It's the transparency, you should include it in the command or mention it.

Comment: JPEG images don't support transparency so no method of converting will preserve that. By default `convert` uses a black background but you can change the color using `-background '#FF0000' -alpha remove`.

Answer (score 30):

The `convert` command found on many Linux distributions is installed as part of the ImageMagick suite. Here's the bash code to run `convert` on all PNG files in a directory and avoid that double extension problem:

```
for img in *.png; do
    filename=${img%.*}
    convert "$filename.png" "$filename.jpg"
done
```

Comment: According to the man page for convert: "The  convert  program is a member of the ImageMagick(1) suite of tools."

Comment: You are correct. For some reason I thought it was part of a different library. Either way the code I posted above is the correct way to automate batch conversion within a directory.

Comment: You can use bash expansion to improve that command like: `for f in *.png; do convert "$f" "${f/%png/jpg}"; done`

Comment: just remember it's case sensitive.  my camera name it as *.JPG and didn't realize this in first instance.

Answer (score 21):

## tl;dr

For those who just want the simplest commands:

**Convert** and **keep** original files:

```
mogrify -format jpg *.png
```

**Convert** and **remove** original files:

```
mogrify -format jpg *.png && rm *.png
```

## Batch Converting Explained

Kinda late to the party, but just to clear up all of the confusion for someone who may not be very comfortable with cli, here's a super dumbed-down reference and explanation.

**Example Directory**

```
bar.png
foo.png
foobar.jpg
```

## Simple Convert

Keeps all original png files as well as creates jpg files.

```
mogrify -format jpg *.png
```

**Result**

```
bar.png
bar.jpg
foo.png
foo.jpg
foobar.jpg
```

**Explanation**

- [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) is part of the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) suite of tools for image processing.

  - mogrify processes images *in place*, meaning the original file is overwritten, with the exception of the `-format` option. (From [the site](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php): `This tool is similar to convert except that the original image file is overwritten (unless you change the file suffix with the -format option)`)
- The [`- format`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#format) option specifies that you will be changing the format, and the next argument needs to be the type (in this case, jpg).
- Lastly, `*.png` is the input files (all files ending in .png).

## Convert and Remove

Converts all png files to jpg, removes original.

```
mogrify -format jpg *.png && rm *.png
```

**Result**

```
bar.jpg
foo.jpg
foobar.jpg
```

**Explanation**

- The first part is the exact same as above, it will create new jpg files.
- The `&&` is a boolean operator. In short:

  - When a program terminates, it returns an exit status. A status of `0` means no errors.
  - Since `&&` performs [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), the right part will only be performed if *there were no errors*. This is useful because you may not want to delete all of the original files if there was an error converting them.
- The `rm` command deletes files.

## Fancy Stuff

Now here's some goodies for the people who *are* comfortable with the cli.

If you want some output while it's converting files:

```
for i in *.png; do mogrify -format jpg "$i" && rm "$i"; echo "$i converted to ${i%.*}.jpg"; done
```

Convert all png files in all subdirectories and give output for each one:

```
find . -iname '*.png' | while read i; do mogrify -format jpg "$i" && rm "$i"; echo "Converted $i to ${i%.*}.jpg"; done
```

Convert all png files in all subdirectories, put all of the resulting jpgs into the `all` directory, number them, remove original png files, and display output for each file as it takes place:

```
n=0; find . -iname '*.png' | while read i; do mogrify -format jpg "$i" && rm "$i"; fn="all/$((n++)).jpg"; mv "${i%.*}.jpg" "$fn"; echo "Moved $i to $fn"; done
```

Comment: Probably the best answer provided you get rid of the `while read` part (replace it or remove it all together)...

Comment: @don_crissti, what's wrong with while read?

Comment: It's error prone (unless you're 100% sure you're dealing with sane file names) and slow (like in very, very, very slow).

Comment: What is the default JPG quality, and how can file timestamps be preserved?

Comment: @DanDascalescu The methods above (except the last one) will preserve filenames, but replace their extension, so timestamped files should be okay (always make a copy and test first). According to ImageMagick, "The default is to use the estimated quality of your input image if it can be determined, otherwise 92" (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) Quality can be specified with -quality <number> where <number> is 1 to 100.

Comment: Thanks. `mogrify -format jpg foo.png` created foo.jpg with the current timestamp though. I wanted to copy the timestamp of foo.png into foo.jpg, and I don't see anything of that nature in the [options](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php).

Answer (score 9):

The actual "`png2jpg`" command you are looking for is in reality split into two commands called `pngtopnm` and `cjpeg`, and they are part of the `netpbm` and `libjpeg-progs` packages, respectively.

```
png2pnm foo.png | cjpeg > foo.jpeg
```

Answer (score 9):

```
find . -name "*.png" -print0 | xargs -0 mogrify -format jpg -quality 50
```

Comment: Thanks for a deep/recursive directory one-line solution which leaves the resulting `*.jpg` files next to the original `*.png` files, shows how to reduce file size/quality and doesn't break because of any odd characters in directory or file name.

Answer (score 5):

my quick solution
`for i in $(ls | grep .png); do convert $i $(echo $i.jpg | sed s/.png//g); done`

Comment: This has got to be one of the ugliest, most convoluted command-lines I've ever seen

Comment: @evilsoup honestly, this is elegant for shell scripts. Claiming it is convoluted isn't fair.

Comment: @MaxHowell man. No. Here would be an elegant version of this: `for f in ./*.png; do convert "$f" "${f%.*}.jpg"; done`. That avoids the completely unnecessary `ls`, `grep` and `sed` calls (and `echo`, but IIRC that's a bash builtin and so will have no/very little performance impact), and gets rid of two pipes and two subshells, *and* involves less typing. It's even slightly more portable, since not all versions of `ls` are safe to parse.

Comment: @evilsoup I stand corrected! Good job.

Answer (score 4):

For batch processing:

```
for img in *.png; do
  convert "$img" "$img.jpg"
done
```

You will end up with file names like image1.png.jpg though.

This will work in bash, and maybe bourne. I don't know about other shells, but the only difference would likely be the loop syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Many years too late, there's a [png2jpeg](https://sourceforge.net/projects/png2jpeg/) utility specifically for this purpose, which I authored.

Adapting the code by @Marcin:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for img in *.png
do
    filename=${img%.*}
    png2jpeg -q 95 -o "$filename.jpg" "$filename.png"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to convert when the files span more than one directory.  My original one was TGA to PNG

```
find . -name "*.tga" -type f | sed 's/\.tga$//' | xargs -I% convert %.tga %.png
```

The concept is you `find` the files you need, strip off the extension then add it back in with `xargs`.  So for PNG to JPG, you'd change the extensions and do one extra thing to deal with alpha channels namely setting the background (in this example white, but you can change it) then flatten the image

```
find . -name "*.png" -type f | sed 's/\.png$//' | xargs -I% convert %.png -background white -flatten  %.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

If your PNG is transparent, try adding a black bg before converting:

```
mogrify -format jpg -background black -flatten *.png
```

or a white bg:

```
mogrify -format jpg -background white -flatten *.png
```

Comment: Thanks. Last comment but saved my from going down a rabbit hole figuring out why ? >> mogrify: unable to open image 'jpg:': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3496.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same `bash` solution but with `ffmpeg` converting:

```
for i in *.png ; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.jpg" ; done
```

Comment: is it possible to compress the image, jpg to jpg or jpeg to jpeg?

Comment: Should work. Please try this and let me know. Just change the line's `.png` to `.jpg`.

Comment: just to confirm is it this command ```ffmpeg -i input.jpg output.jpg```

Comment: That command you mentioned should recompress a single jpg.

Answer (score 0):

I made this script,for jpg to png it works well:

```bash
#!/bin/bash                                                                    
clear
# Remove Spaces in the names                        
for f in *\ *; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done
# Number of files to convert                         
files=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg')
total=$(wc -l <<< "$files")
files=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -prune -name '*.JPG')
total=$(( $total + $(wc -l <<< "$files") ))
files=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -prune -name '*.jpeg')
total=$(( $total + $(wc -l <<< "$files") ))
files=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -prune -name '*.JPEG')
total=$(( $total + $(wc -l <<< "$files") ))
echo "There is  $total JPG files"
# Convert                                               
echo "    Convert is going on..."
 for img in *.*; do
       filename=${img%.*}
       form3="${img: -3}"
       form4="${img: -4}"
     if [[ $form3 =~ "JPG" ]] || [[ $form3 =~ "jpg" ]];
        then
        convert "$filename.$form3" "$filename.png"
        echo "  $img  ===>  ${img%.$form3}.png"
     elif [[ $form4 =~ "JPEG" ]] || [[ $form4 =~ "jpeg" ]];
        then
        convert "$filename.$form4" "$filename.png"
        echo "  $img  ==>  ${img%.$form4}.png"
     else echo
    fi
 done
 echo " Convert finished !"
# Remove                                                                      
echo " Removing originals files"
echo
shopt -s nocaseglob
 for i in *.jpg; do
rm -v $i
 done
  for i in *.jpeg; do
rm -v $i
  done
echo
ls --color=auto -C
exit
```

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer given 13 years ago?

Comment: To elaborate on @Toto's answer: doesn't mogrify (as mentioned in that accepted answer) do this for you? It's a nice effort though :)