# How do I control the compression rate of mogrify?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, images, conversion

I want to do something like

```
mogrify -format jpg *.png
```

However, I want to encode the jpg at a higher quality than the default. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
mogrify -format jpg -quality 100 *.png
```

According to the [official documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) the `quality` parameter can be 1 - 100 and the effect varies depending on the resulting format.

- For JPG output a value of  1 gives worst quality and highest compression; a value of 100 gives best quality and lowest compression.
- For PNG files the `quality` parameter only changes the lossless compression strategies used, so the speed of compression and the resulting file size can be affected but image quality remains the same.

With any Linux command, you can enter

```
man [command]
```

To see the help page that list out the information and parameters available.

Comment: *Almost* any Linux command.

Comment: Or you can avoid the terror of `man` by using `bro`. [Install](http://bropages.org/).

Comment: Or you can just Google it and read the SE answer for the specific parameter you're looking for, which is usually faster than scanning the man page for it.