# best freeware for doing batch conversion of jpg to png

Tags: windows-xp, conversion, jpeg, png

Which is the best freeware for converting jpg files in different folder to png in a batch process on a windows xp?

Comment: I thought for sure we'd had this Q, but the other ones were about linux.  Anyway, [Wil's answer, imagemagick](http://superuser.com/questions/71028/batch-converting-png-to-jpg-in-linux/71030#71030), applies here also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

while [irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) is officially a viewer, it does a pretty good job at he sort of batch conversions you're talking about

Answer (score 3):

- [nconvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert.html) from [xnview](http://www.xnview.com/en/index.html) - batch utility to convert graphic files, support of more than 400 graphics formats!
- [xnview](http://www.xnview.com/en/index.html) by itself (if you like GUI tools)
- [imagemagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) (windows version is [here](ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/windows/ImageMagick-windows.zip))

irfanview is ugly, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

[FastStone Photo Resizer](http://www.faststone.org/FSResizerDetail.htm) lets you convert images in batch mode. It supports JPEG, BMP, GIF, PNG, TIFF and JPEG2000 formats.

[image]

[x2y](http://x2y.sourceforge.net/features.html) can also convert multiple images from different directories to a new format in batch mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

R.I.O.T.
http://luci.criosweb.ro/riot/