# How can I save all images inside in a .docx to TIFF format?

Tags: microsoft-word, tiff, pictures

How can I save all images inside in a .docx to TIFF format?

We intend to submit an article with the requirement that **all its figures** are shipped separately in **TIFF** format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could open the .DOCX file with a Zip decompression utility (either the one built into Windows, or perhaps [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or alike).

Once you have it open you can navigate to the "Word" folder contained in the file, and the "Media" sub-folder inside that.

In there you should see all of your images (etc.), and you can just copy/drag-n-drop them out onto the desktop, or another working folder.

Once you have that done you can use you favorite [batch image processor](https://superuser.com/questions/162060/best-freeware-for-doing-batch-conversion-of-jpg-to-png) to [convert them](https://superuser.com/questions/77429/using-gimp-to-batch-convert-images-to-another-format-in-windows) to TIFF.