# “Pixel format 'yuvj420p' is not supported” when converting image to video using CUDA hardware acceleration

Tags: ffmpeg, cuda

I'm trying to convert an image to a video using CUDA hardware acceleration but I can't get it to work.

The basic command I have is this one:

> ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuvid -i tests/MediaSamples/portrait_0.jpg -t 10 out.mp4

And I'm getting this error:

```
[AVHWFramesContext @ 0x32d3f00] Pixel format 'yuvj420p' is not supported
[mjpeg @ 0x2d18480] Error initializing a CUDA frame pool
cuvid hwaccel requested for input stream #0:0, but cannot be initialized.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
```

I've tried setting the pixel format like so, but that didn't help:

> ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuvid -pix_fmt yuv420p -i tests/MediaSamples/portrait_0.jpg -t 10 out.mp4

I've also tried many other flags but can't get anything to work. Any idea what the issue might be?

For information this is the full log:

```
ffmpeg version N-96615-gc35382a Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
  configuration: --enable-nonfree --disable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-openssl --enable-libx264 --enable-cuda-sdk --enable-nvenc --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/ssl/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/ssl/lib' --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 67.101 / 58. 67.101
  libavformat    58. 37.100 / 58. 37.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 73.100 /  7. 73.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, image2, from 'tests/MediaSamples/portrait_0.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 40237 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1600x900 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[AVHWFramesContext @ 0x32d3f00] Pixel format 'yuvj420p' is not supported
[mjpeg @ 0x2d18480] Error initializing a CUDA frame pool
cuvid hwaccel requested for input stream #0:0, but cannot be initialized.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
[libx264 @ 0x2d1e840] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x2d1e840] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x2d1e840] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x2d1e840] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=24 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.37.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1600x900 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.67.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with JPEGs. As a workaround, you can [convert](https://superuser.com/questions/71028/batch-converting-png-to-jpg-in-linux) the images to PNG first using ImageMagick then use that in ffmpeg:

```
mogrify -format png "*.jpg"
```

Or if you only have one image:

```
convert image.jpg image.png
```

(Mogrify will create the files with the same name as the input.)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you posted this, but:

```
 -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda
```

Should work for that now.